# Azure Web API call with token authorisation

Tags: azure, access-token, azure-web-app-service, azure-scheduler

I have a Web API (all my code) method that I want to be called on a schedule from within Azure.  I have it all working.  I can specify the URL, set up a schedule and it works fine.  What I want to do though is restrict the call to a certain 'system' user.

All other Web API methods are called from a Web Site.  The Web site allows the user to login and receive an 'access token' and then that token is sent along with all other requests.  So a two-step process.  This all works fine too.

How do I pass the 'system' user/password to the Web API method from within the Azure scheduler?  It looked pretty straight forward, choose Basic Authentication and then enter the user/password combination.  It still calls the Web API method, but its not authenticated?  I'm not sure how I get the User authenticated 'before' calling the Web API method?

Answer (score 1):

You probably use an Identity Provider like Azure Active Directory. You should use a **service principal** which represents your schedule application that is allowed to call your API instead of user principal (your system user).

Read more:
[Application and service principal objects in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-objects)

So within the *Authentication Settings* you should choose Active Directory OAuth and provide the neccessary values:

[image]

Basic Authentication must be configured within your WebAPI, its not related to the token authentication which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

> It still calls the Web API method, but its not authenticated?
>
> I'm not sure how I get the User authenticated 'before' calling the Web API method?

According to your description, it seems that you want to use **Basic Authentication** in Web API. Just like  your guess, we could enter user name and password straight forward by using [Basic Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication). I have created a simple demo, if I want to read the data in Web API, I need to be authenticated first. You could refer to my code:

Code in Web API project

Create BasicAuthHttpModule.cs: (specific your user name and password)

```
public class BasicAuthHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {
        private const string Realm = "My Realm";

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        // Register event handlers
        context.AuthenticateRequest += OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest;
        context.EndRequest += OnApplicationEndRequest;
    }

    private static void SetPrincipal(IPrincipal principal)
    {
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        }
    }

    // TODO: Here is where you would validate the username and password.
    private static bool CheckPassword(string username, string password)
    {
        return username == "peter" && password == "Password123!"; // you also could read user name and password from your Azure SQL database
    }

    private static void AuthenticateUser(string credentials)
    {
        try
        {
            var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
            credentials = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(credentials));

            int separator = credentials.IndexOf(':');
            string name = credentials.Substring(0, separator);
            string password = credentials.Substring(separator + 1);

            if (CheckPassword(name, password))
            {
                var identity = new GenericIdentity(name);
                SetPrincipal(new GenericPrincipal(identity, null));
            }
            else
            {
                // Invalid username or password.
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            // Credentials were not formatted correctly.
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        }
    }

    private static void OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var authHeader = request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (authHeader != null)
        {
            var authHeaderVal = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authHeader);

            // RFC 2617 sec 1.2, "scheme" name is case-insensitive
            if (authHeaderVal.Scheme.Equals("basic",
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                authHeaderVal.Parameter != null)
            {
                AuthenticateUser(authHeaderVal.Parameter);
            }
        }
    }

    // If the request was unauthorized, add the WWW-Authenticate header 
    // to the response.
    private static void OnApplicationEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        if (response.StatusCode == 401)
        {
            response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate",
                string.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", Realm));
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

Code in web.config:

```
<modules>
<add name="BasicAuthHttpModule"
         type=" [your project name].[folder name].BasicAuthHttpModule, [your project name]"/>
<!--Just like this: WebApiAzure1.BasicAuthor.BasicAuthHttpModule,WebApiAzure1-->
</modules>
```

Code in Api Controller:

```
       [Authorize] //add authorize attribute for specific method
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
```

You could see the result like this:

[image]

Comment: Currently trying this code.  Slow reply - moved house.  The code runs and appears to work as expected. It's still saying unauthoised when it hits the controller action though.  I'll investigate a bit more.

Comment: Check your username and password. Please mak sure they are correct.

Comment: The code above is definitely being called with the correct User Id / Password.  Looking into the documentation, it would seem that I need to use Azure Directory Services?

Comment: No. I just provide a document about Basic Authentication in Web API. I suggest you could follow steps in above article(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication).

Comment: if the reply help you solve the problem, you can mark it as answer to close this thread.

Comment: I still can't get this wot work in my case.  It's still outstanding.  Probably specific to my scenario.  When I determine the answer I will post here.